# Timeout or sleep within a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

In it's simplest form my code is below, I am looping through an array and removing a random item in each iteration until the loop length is 0. I'd like to add a sleep or delay in each iteration but I'm not sure the best way to achieve this in angular1.x or plain js.

I have found this question [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) but can't get the top rated answer to work.

Can anyone please help with this:

```
while($scope.players.length > 0){

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.players.length);
    $scope.players.splice(random, 1);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for that purpose

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
>
> The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until
>   clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.
>
> The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as the parameter for
>   the clearInterval() method.
>
> Tip: 1000 ms = 1 second.
>
> Tip: To execute a function only once, after a specified number of
>   milliseconds, use the setTimeout() method.

**Example**

```
function _do(){
   if($scope.players.length > 0){

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.players.length);
    $scope.players.splice(random, 1);

   } else clearInterval(_loop);
}

var _loop = setInterval(_do,1000); //Sleep for 1 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)?

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
var interval = null;


function removeArray() {
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  array.splice(random, 1);
  console.log(array);

  if (array.length == 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

interval = setInterval(removeArray, 1000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT -> After a useful comment, I realize $timeout is not the best answer.  So I'll agree with other answers here about using an interval, but I would still suggest using Angular's built-in [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('MyApp', []);

  angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

  MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval'];

  function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {

    $scope.players = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    var INTERVAL_LENGTH = 1000; // This can be however long you want
    var INTERVAL_COUNT = $scope.players.length;

    if (INTERVAL_COUNT > 0) {
      $interval(function() {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.players.length);
        $scope.players.splice(random, 1);
      }, INTERVAL_LENGTH, INTERVAL_COUNT).then(function() {
        $scope.players = 'done!';
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span>{{ players }}</span>
</div>
```

`$interval` also returns a promise which is resolved when the last iteration is complete, so any asynchronous work you want to do after the interval is complete can be easily handled.

---

Previous answer:

Angular provides the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service.  After injecting it as a dependency in your controller:

```
var PAUSE_AMOUNT = 500; // This can be however long you want
while($scope.players.length > 0){
    $timeout(function() {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.players.length);
        $scope.players.splice(random, 1);
    }, PAUSE_AMOUNT);
}
```

This will pause for 500 ms between each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: there is no while loop in your answer, and no exit strategy either

Comment: I was referring to the while loop in the original question, I'll add it in the code for clarity

Comment: I just don't think it will pause execution of the while loop :p

Answer (score 0):

The SO answer you have mentioned in the question also works well. See the snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.players = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  var ele = angular.element(document.querySelector('#playersEle'));
  ele.html($scope.players);
  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  async function demo() {
    while ($scope.players.length > 0) {
      console.log('Taking a break...');
      await sleep(2000);
      console.log('Two second later');
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.players.length);
      $scope.players.splice(random, 1);
      ele.html($scope.players);
    }
  }
  demo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span id="playersEle"></span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setInterval` function. 
This will keep calling the function after an amount of time.
Example:

```
var myFunction = function () {
  //do something
};
setInterval(myFunction, 1000)
```

In this example it will call `myFunction` every 1000 mini seconds. 
KEY:

1000 ms = 1 s

You can also cancel a `setInterval` with the script:

```
//create an variable for the setInterval
var intervalId = setInterval(myFunction, 2500);
//That is 2.5 seconds
//Now to cancel the interval:

clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Use the `clearInterval();` to stop an interval.
in the `()` put the interval name you want to stop.

**CALLING MULTIPLE FUNCTIONS OR DO SOMETHING:**

To call multiple functions at a time or do something else, use this:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
  //put whatever you want here, I'll put some examples
  callAFunction();
  inputFunction("123Example...");
  alert("Hello!"); 
  //Not a function, just as I said, you can do whatever you want here
  console.log("setInterval Is great"); //Not a function!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  //This is a comment
  /*
    This is
    another
  */
  functionCall();
  //here is the end of this variable
}, 100); //the number is the amount of ms after it loops again
```

You see? This is very useful! 
Tell me if I said something you don't want to do.

^_^